# Open different links with the same beginning

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, hyperlink

I have a NSObject and array containing different information about celebrities. It includes a Wikipedia link which is stored in a string to each celebrity. I have a button which is supposed to open the link and direct the user to the specific celebrity's Wikipedia page, but not all celebrities have a wikipedia page and in this case would I like to show an UIAlertController when the button is pressed instead.

I have written an if-statement which successfully shows a UIAlertController, **but how do I open the specific url link attached to the person?**

I have come up with two ideas of solving this (But I can't get them to work):

1.All existing links have the same beginning, "https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/", and the celebrities who don't have one will simply have an empty string. Is there a way to open the link if the string contains/recognises the beginning of the wikipedia link and only show the alert if the string is empty (= no wikipedia link at all)?

```
@IBAction func ReadMoreTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

     //The celebrity's wikipedia link is stored in the "WikiSegue"
     if WikiSegue == "https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/..." {

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : WikiSegue)!)

} else {

  //Show "missing wikipedia page" alert

    }

} //End of ReadMoreTapped button
```

2.Or is it possible to call the alert if there is no wikipedia link within the string (it's empty)? Using something like this?

```
 @IBAction func ReadMoreTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

     //The wikipedia link is stored in the "WikiSegue"
     if WikiSegue.isEmpty == true  {

   //Show "missing wikipedia page" alert

} else {

 UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string : WikiSegue)!)

    }

} //End of ReadMoreTapped button
```

I don't believe this can be such a hard fix, but I'm just starting out with coding so all help/ideas would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your array contains same kind of objects. And objects contains a string field which has the url. First you should check if that field contains the string (maybe with string.characters.count > 0) than try to create NSURL with that string like below.

```
if let wikiURL = NSURL(string: "URL STRING") {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(wikiURL)
} else {
    // Show alert
}
```

Comment: I used the string.character.count --> worked perfectly! Thank you!